# Returning a list from a function with many lists in it

Tags: python, list, function

**Noob question ahead**

So I am making a basic text-based RPG just to get me back into the basics of Python after being gone for a few months.

I'm trying to make a function that has all of the items in it as lists, and when the name of an item is called, it returns the 'stats' of the item.

E.g.

```
def itemlist(input):
    item1 = [name, damage, etc]
    item2 = [name, damage, etc]
    item3 = [name, damage, etc]
    ...
    return(####)
```

Here I want the return to pass back the item list that has the name of the item in the variable 'input', so this function will be called something like

```
item = itemlist(item2)
```

however I get an error saying that 'item2' is not defined in the main() function that I run the request in.

Am I just being an idiot or is there some solution that I'm just missing?

Comment: It looks like you want a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: ... I'm not sure I understand you, but if you don't have an `item2` defined in `main` (or globally, or closed over `main`) then I'm not sure why you expect that to work.

Comment: What patrick said. Your function doesn't know that the input is supposed to be one of the items. With a dict you might not even need the function.

Comment: `item2` is a local name in the `itemlist()` function, nowhere else. However, you should not be using separate variables for all those lists in the first place. Use a dictionary: `itemlist = {'item1': [....], 'item2': [....]}`, and `itemlist['item2']` will get you the correct list from that.

Answer (score 1):

`item2` is defined inside of `itemlist`, not also (apparently) somewhere that your `main` function can see it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to store the items.
The keys would be the item names, and the values, their respective stats.

```
items = {'sword': (12, 27), 'dagger': (42, 76), ...}
```

Then you would simply get the dictionary's values:

```
>>> items['sword']
(12, 27)
```